# How to Install Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli

Tags: c#, .net-core

When i am trying to install
 "dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli" it is throwing Error.
I had install latest dotnet sdk.
C# extension also installed in VS code

```
PS D:\DotNetCore\MvcMovie> dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli
error NU1101: Unable to find package microsoft.web.librarymanager.cli.
 No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolderThe tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'microsoft.web.librarymanager.cli' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET Core tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify the tool version in the command with `--version`, see an example below:

```
dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli --version 2.1.113
```

You can see all versions for `Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager` [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli/).